# RAID Hard drive partition from one motherbord to another?

Tags: motherboard, bios, raid, sata

I had ASUS P5K3 Deluxe/WiFi-AP which was working for 4 years. Yesturday it burned out... literaly with smoke and fire... So I plan on  getting  DFI LanParty LT X48-T3RS (Intel X48, DDR3) as a replacement. I had RAID of 5 satas. I do not remember what type of RAID it was but I know for sure that the drives were not mirrored. I have no regrets of loosing it but still I wonder what are my chances of saving the data? Meaning if I take the drives and plug them into a new RAID will I still have access to the data? I do remember the order that the drives were connected to the previous motherboard.

Comment: "literally with smoke and fire"  makes me fell kinda scared... before replacing with a new motherboard find out what happened to the previous... or quite playing with fire around it. :P

Comment: Perhaps it was RAID-6? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID_6#RAID_6 It seems to be the only one with 5 discs.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner you can have more than the drives that are shown in the wiki for RAID's...  For example a RAID-0 can have 3, 4, 5 or more drives.  Most common raid is RAID-5 which is a RAID-6 only there is only 1 parity.  That would be the best assumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not really any way to know until you plug it in. If you were replacing your motherboard with the same type of motherboard, then I would say there is a very good chance of recovering your array. However, if your new motherboard supports RAID, there's a chance it will have a slightly different format than your previous motherboard, which would prevent simply mounting the drives. You can search for a [raid recovery tool](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=raid+recovery+tools), or simply trial and error of getting the new motherboard to detect the drives (you'll have to figure out the raid level and stripe size, as well as preventing the motherboard from initializing the disks when you try to create the array in the BIOS).

Either way, it's most likely not going to be simple.